# Managing many jars via WebAppContext extraClasspath

Tags: java, jetty, classpath

I have an embedded jetty server that hot deploys webapps. When deploying the other wars, I add a deployment descriptor.xml to the directory to configure the webappcontext.  I wish to add a DIRECTORY of jars that gets built in another location to the classpath of the hot deployed war (/extJars).  I see how to do this within the webapp descriptor.xml, and I can accomplish this by stating individual jars, but I have tried multiple configurations for trying to simply read ALL jars in this directory, and nothing has worked.  Here is my otherWebApp.xml, we'll call it, with a configuration that works, and commented out configurations that don't work.  Thanks.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
    <Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
        <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" default="." />/extApps/otherWebApp.war</Set>
        <Set name="contextPath">/otherWebApp</Set>
        <Set name="tempDirectory" ><SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/jetty/webapps/otherWebApp</Set>  
<Set name="extraClasspath"><SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars/cadi-core-1.0.12.jar,<SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars/cadi-aaf-1.0.12.jar,<SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars/GLCookieDecryption-1.0.jar,<SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars/rosetta-1.1.1.jar,<SystemProperty name="AJSC_HOME" />/extJars/env-1.4.2.jar,<SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars/dme2-2.5.22.jar</Set>
<!-- <Set name="extraClasspath"><SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars/</Set>
    </Configure>  doesn't work -->
<!-- <Set name="extraClasspath"><SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars/*</Set>
    </Configure> doesn't work -->
<!-- <Set name="extraClasspath"><SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars/*.jar</Set>
    </Configure>  doesn't work -->
<!-- <Set name="extraClasspath"><SystemProperty name="JETTY_HOME" />/extJars</Set>
    </Configure> doesn't work -->
```

Comment: Do you work with the `WebAppContext` in java code before you add it as a handler to the server? or do you rely on the `DeploymentManager` to do that?

Comment: Are these `extraClasspath` jars added to all `WebAppContext` s in your embedded server? or just specific ones?

Comment: I am using a Deployment Manager to create a Hot Deployable Folder location.  Then, I am adding the otherWebApp.war and otherWebApp.xml to the folder, and the Deployment Manager hot deploys the war based on the xml. Technically speaking, these extra jars are being added by a classloader for the main webapp, but these jars also need to be used by the otherWebApp. I guess overall design/workflow is I have a main jetty.xml that sets up the Deployment manager which deploys both the main webAppContext AND the hot deploy folder. I simply want all extJars to be on otherWebApp classpath using the xml.

Comment: And, no, for clarity, I am not using any java code for webappcontext.  It is all xml

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 choices.

**1: Use Parent Loader Priority**

In embedded, tell the WebAppContext to use parent loader priority. (this will favor server classes over webapp classes)

```xml
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/example</Set>
  <Set name="war">example.war</Set>
  <Set name="parentLoaderPriority">true</Set>
</Configure>
```

This does have a side effect that if the server class does any caching of information (a common technique in many libraries) then that cache is now available for all webapps.

**2: Use A Custom DeploymentManager Binding for managing WebAppClassloader**

Each WebAppContext uses a WebAppClassloader that can be configured to:

1. Expose certain classes from server classloader
2. Establish what the WebAppContext does if there is a conflict between the webapp and the server.

Since you are using the [`DeploymentManager`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/deploy/DeploymentManager.html), this can be standardized via the Bindings techniques.

The Binding itself: `ExposeServerCommonBinding.java`

```java
package jetty;

import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.graph.Node;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class ExposeServerCommonBinding implements AppLifeCycle.Binding
{
    public String[] getBindingTargets()
    {
        return new String[]
        { "deploying" };
    }

    public void processBinding(Node node, App app) throws Exception
    {
        ContextHandler handler = app.getContextHandler();
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("No Handler created for App: " + app);
        }

        if (handler instanceof WebAppContext)
        {
            WebAppContext webapp = (WebAppContext)handler;

            // System classes (or namespaces) present in server classloader to expose to webapp
            webapp.addSystemClass("org.apache.log4j.");
            webapp.addSystemClass("org.slf4j.");
            webapp.addSystemClass("org.apache.commons.logging.");

            // Server classes that cannot be overridden by webapp
            webapp.addServerClass("-org.apache.log4j.");
            webapp.addServerClass("-org.slf4j.");
            webapp.addServerClass("-org.apache.commons.logging.");
        }
    }
}
```

And how to use it

```java
DeploymentManager mgr = new DeploymentManager();

WebAppProvider provider = new WebAppProvider();
provider.setMonitoredDirResource(Resource.newResource(new File("./webapps/")));
mgr.addAppProvider(provider);

mgr.addLifeCycleBinding(new ExposeServerCommonBinding());
```

This technique will apply to all WebAppContexts that are deployed via the DeploymentManager, allowing you to apply these rules equally to all webapps.

**3: Use A Custom DeploymentManager Binding for managing extraClasspath**

Here's another Binding alternative you can use to pre-build the extraClasspath at the server side, and when a WebApp is deployed, it automatically adds these extraClasspath to the WebApp.

```java
package jetty;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.App;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle;
import org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.graph.Node;
import org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class CommonExtraClasspathBinding implements AppLifeCycle.Binding
{
    private List<File> extraClasspath = new ArrayList<>();

    public String[] getBindingTargets()
    {
        return new String[] { "deploying" };
    }

    public void addAllJars(File dir)
    {
        for (File file : dir.listFiles())
        {
            if (!file.isFile())
            {
                continue;
            }
            if (file.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.ENGLISH).equals(".jar"))
            {
                addJar(file);
            }
        }
    }

    public void addJar(File jar)
    {
        if (jar.exists() && jar.isFile())
        {
            extraClasspath.add(jar);
        }
    }

    public void processBinding(Node node, App app) throws Exception
    {
        ContextHandler handler = app.getContextHandler();
        if (handler == null)
        {
            throw new NullPointerException("No Handler created for App: " + app);
        }

        if (handler instanceof WebAppContext)
        {
            WebAppContext webapp = (WebAppContext)handler;

            StringBuilder xtraCp = new StringBuilder();
            boolean delim = false;
            for (File cp : extraClasspath)
            {
                if (delim)
                {
                    xtraCp.append(File.pathSeparatorChar);
                }
                xtraCp.append(cp.getAbsolutePath());
                delim = true;
            }

            webapp.setExtraClasspath(xtraCp.toString());
        }
    }
}
```