# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext' is not of type 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext'

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jetty

I am trying to add extra classpaths to my web project. To do so I have followed [this guide](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-classloading.html) and created a `jetty-env.xml` file with the following content

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
    <Set name="extraClasspath">lib/ivy/</Set>     
</Configure>
```

and put it in the `WEB-INF/` folder. However when I start Jetty I get the following exception:

```
2017-04-13 15:55:41.937:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@51931956{/server,file:/C:/Users/foo/project/webapps/server/,STARTING}{C:\Users\foo\project\webapps\server}
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Object of class 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext' is not of type 'org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext'. Object Class and type Class are from different loaders. in file:/C:/Users/foo/project/webapps/server/WEB-INF/jetty-env.xml
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$JettyXmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:296)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.configure(XmlConfiguration.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.plus.webapp.EnvConfiguration.configure(EnvConfiguration.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.configure(WebAppContext.java:479)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:505)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:440)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
...
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:112)
```

What did I do wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out. I had a [jetty-all](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.jetty.aggregate/jetty-all) jar file in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder. Removing it fixed the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot add extra classpath entries from within the WebApp startup (its too late, the `WebAppClassloader` already exists by that point).

That has to be defined outside of the `WebAppContext` deployment so that the startup of the WebApp can use it.

You'll need a XML deployable.

Assuming your war is `${jetty.base}/webapps/myserver.war`

Create `${jetty.base}/webapps/myserver.xml`

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
                           "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/myserver</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/myserver.war</Set>
  <Set name="extraClasspath">/full/path/to/my/extra/lib/ivy/</Set>
</Configure>
```

Also note: `extraClasspath` cannot be a relative path. It has to be an absolute path.

If you have an expanded directory webapp deployment, consider a similar approach.

Assuming you have a webapp at `${jetty.base}/webapps/foo/`

Create `${jetty.base}/webapps/foo.xml` file

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN"
                           "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_3.dtd">

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/foo</Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.webapps" default="."/>/foo/</Set>
  <Set name="extraClasspath">/full/path/to/my/extra/lib/ivy/</Set>
</Configure>
```

Comment: I don't have war files but inside my webapps folder there are a bunch of subfolders, each one is a different project. How can I configure it in this case so that the extraClasspath is available to all of those projects?

Comment: I did as your edited answer, but now I have the exact same problem as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26128278/managing-many-jars-via-webappcontext-extraclasspath where I have to manually specify each of the JARs inside the folder.

Comment: That is correct, there's no glob support in `extraClasspath`, you have to specify each classpath root object (either a directory to an expanded classpath reference, or a jar file) you want the webapp to use.  Frankly, if you have more than 2 extraClasspath entries, you have a deployment anti-pattern and need to evaluate why you need that extraClasspath.